# How can I get the default UICollectionView cell size?

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm implementing the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`'s `collectionView:layout: sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath` method, and to calculate the new cell size, I have to access the default one.

**My question is:** How do I access the default cell size as defined in storyboard, from my code?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found the answer while composing this question, thus, just to share with you, here's some sample code:

```
- (CGSize) collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

    // Get the default cell size as defined in storyboard:
    CGSize defaultSize = [(UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)collectionViewLayout itemSize];

    if (something) {
        return defaultSize;
    }

    CGSize newSize = defaultSize;
    newSize.height *= 2;

    return newSize;
}
```